# Is it right for the Baal Koreh to greet the oleh before the reading

Tags: blessing, torah-reading

Why I am asking: I was called up to read from the Torah. The Baal Koreh when I came there, said “Good Morning”. It felt wrong to answer him, just before opening the sefer to make the brocho.

The question: What do the sources say about whether it is allowed for the baal koreh to greet a person having the aliyah with a 'Good Morning' before the oleh makes his brocho and is it allowed for the oleh to respond?

My Question is not dependent on whether the oleh is wearing tefillin, see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4231/speaking-while-wearing-tefillin).

Comment: Everything between Alyos (the brochos and the reading)is optional - blessings, donations, inviting to a Kiddush, etc. So why not greeting?

Comment: Did you have a halachic reason for thinking that it would be wrong to greet/respond? Is this because you feel that any conversation between aliyot is problematic or is this specific to the role/function of ba'al koreh or an oleh?

Comment: @rosends there is a prohibition to greet people before prayer because God comes first (I'm oversimplifying of course) and a similar sentiment could apply here

Comment: @DoubleAA what is considered "prayer" in that prohibition?

Comment: @rosends My feeling is that there is here a mitzvah to be done and by speaking they are delaying its performance (albeit by a very short time) as in 'מצוה הבא לידך אל תחמיצנה'.